# Displaying a table showing parent with every child node per row

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have the following XML that needs to be displayed in a table, in this format:

*Column 1:*

**Requirement**

REQ-1

REQ-2

REQ-3

REQ-4

*Column 2:*

**Acceptance Test**

AT-1

AT-1

AT-1

AT-2

How can I achieve this using XSLT1.0?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<root>
<Item type="Acceptance Test">
  <jav_acc_id>AT-1</jav_acc_id>
  <Relationships>
     <Item type="Acceptance Test Requirements">
        <related_id>
           <Item type="Requirement">
              <item_number>REQ-1</item_number>
           </Item>
        </related_id>
     </Item>
     <Item type=" Acceptance Test Requirements ">
        <related_id>
           <Item type="Requirement">
              <item_number>REQ-2</item_number>
           </Item>
        </related_id>
     </Item>
     <Item type=" Acceptance Test Requirements ">
        <related_id>
           <Item type="Requirement">
              <item_number>REQ-3</item_number>
           </Item>
        </related_id>
     </Item>
    </Relationships>
</Item>
<Item type="Acceptance Test">
  <jav_acc_id>AT-2</jav_acc_id>
  <Relationships>
     <Item type="Acceptance Test Requirements">
        <related_id>
           <Item type="Requirement">
              <item_number>REQ-4</item_number>
           </Item>
        </related_id>
     </Item>
  </Relationships>
</Item>
</root>
```

This is what I have (which creates an output that is SO wrong but I have no idea how to fix it)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
              <th style="text-align:left">Requirement</th>
              <th style="text-align:left">Acceptance Test</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="descendant::Item">
              <tr>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="item_number"/></td>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="jav_acc_id"/></td>
              </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The input that you show is not well-formed XML. Please fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following **well-formed** input:

**XML**

```
<root>
   <Item type="Acceptance Test">
      <jav_acc_id>AT-1</jav_acc_id>
      <Relationships>
         <Item type="Acceptance Test Requirements">
            <related_id>
               <Item type="Requirement">
                  <item_number>REQ-1</item_number>
               </Item>
            </related_id>
         </Item>
         <Item type=" Acceptance Test Requirements ">
            <related_id>
               <Item type="Requirement">
                  <item_number>REQ-2</item_number>
               </Item>
            </related_id>
         </Item>
         <Item type=" Acceptance Test Requirements ">
            <related_id>
               <Item type="Requirement">
                  <item_number>REQ-3</item_number>
               </Item>
            </related_id>
         </Item>
      </Relationships>
   </Item>
   <Item type="Acceptance Test">
      <jav_acc_id>AT-2</jav_acc_id>
      <Relationships>
         <Item type="Acceptance Test Requirements">
            <related_id>
               <Item type="Requirement">
                  <item_number>REQ-4</item_number>
               </Item>
            </related_id>
         </Item>
      </Relationships>
   </Item>
</root>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Requirement</th>
            <th>Acceptance Test</th>
        </tr>   
        <xsl:for-each select="Item/Relationships/Item">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select=".//item_number"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="../../jav_acc_id"/>
                </td>
            </tr>   
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

**Result**

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <th>Requirement</th>
      <th>Acceptance Test</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>REQ-1</td>
      <td>AT-1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>REQ-2</td>
      <td>AT-1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>REQ-3</td>
      <td>AT-1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>REQ-4</td>
      <td>AT-2</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Rendered as:**

[image]

Comment: The table borders don't seem to display at all?

Comment: @User1218 They do display for me (see the picture above).

Comment: I got it to work by changing the XSL stylesheet information at the top. Thank you!